# neo4j browser performing very slowly

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-browser

I am running the query below in Neo4j browser. I have 2 labels and 1 relationship in the database. One label has 50,000 nodes and the other has 1,800 nodes, and there are 48,000 relationships.

`MATCH (u)-[r]->(n)
WITH u, COLLECT(n) AS ns, COLLECT(r) AS rs
WHERE SIZE(ns) > 1
RETURN u, ns, rs`

This query takes about 5 minutes to run, even though the resulting code tab says `Started streaming 7437 records after 98 ms and completed after 199 ms.` I thought this might be due to the visualization process so I went to configuration and put initial node display, max neighbors, and max rows all to 0. It still takes about 5 minutes. Any ideas as to what could be causing this lag?

Answer (score 1):

The lag is probably due to the fact that the server is sending a lot of data to the neo4j browser. Even if you tell the browser to not display all the returned data, it still has to process all of the data being sent from the server.

The browser should respond much quicker if you modified the Cypher query to tell the server to `LIMIT` the amount of data it sends back. For example, to just display 10 `u` nodes and their data:

```
MATCH (u)-[r]->(n)
WITH u, COLLECT(n) AS ns, COLLECT(r) AS rs
WHERE SIZE(ns) > 1
RETURN u, ns, rs
LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: I get a strange error from this when I click the Text tab of the result: `Something went wrong: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined" and the application can't recover.`. Regardless I probably should've mentioned my goal. I am trying to do a speed test on neo4j so limiting the amount of data isn't something I should do for that. Is there another way to query this, maybe without the browser?

Comment: You have already sort of did a speed test. See [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48981726/974731).

Comment: Right, but it doesn't seem entirely correct as it takes much longer for my browser to respond than the 199ms claimed.

Comment: Yes, the browser is slow when processing large amounts of data. But the server is indeed that fast. (In fact, it is faster than the times imply, since the browser is a bottleneck -- the streaming cannot finish until the browser actually reads all the data and stores it in local memory).

Comment: Do you happen to know of some software that could handle the data in a more efficient way? Preferably something light that essentially returns the Text tab of the result?

Comment: You can execute your query from the command line using the [cypher-shell](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/3.4/tools/cypher-shell/) tool.